# How to present a custom save message balloon from javascript in umbraco

Tags: javascript, umbraco

You know that little message balloon that pops up when you save a document?  I want to show that in my custom section.  I see that I can make my page inherit from UmbracoEnsuredPage and use ClientTools.ShowSpeechBubble.  The problem is that I need to be able to display it from javascript on the client side.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Lee Kelleher over at umbraco's forum was able to answer this. http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/19190-Custom-save-message-balloon-from-javascript

Here is the code

```
UmbClientMgr.mainWindow().UmbSpeechBubble.ShowMessage('info', 'This is the header', 'This is the body text.');
```